# Declare and test variable without prior value assignement

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, declare

Given a standard bash environment, is the following behavior shown commonly expected?

```
~ $ declare testa
~ $ declare -p testa
bash: declare: testa: not found
```

At the time of writing, there seem to be differences for the given case in the output across different bash in different OS's (not shown here).

Additionally, is there any definitive bash API manual, reference or other documentation where this case is covered?

Comment: What were you expecting?  You can try the help command :- help declare, -p option and what it does is listed or man bash for further detail

Comment: @grail: Surprising yes! `declare` should have hit the error first time. It is `bash` builtin for sure

Comment: We are having a discussion about this over at [yarn-completion](https://github.com/dsifford/yarn-completion/issues/14). So this comes unexpected on both sides; Maintainer says that behaviour above is unexpected and is out in production with no further probs; I said this behaviour is observable for me, but my test machines seem to be currently aligned to provide the same bash version. Do i miss something from man bash? Per synopsis, all parameters are optional. In other langs declaration is seperate to later value assignement, so yes, i did not expect the observed outcome. What am i missing?

Comment: Can this be related to the [bash 4.4 relase](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2016-09/msg00008.html),  Entry "f.  The `-p' option to declare and similar builtins will display attributes for named variables even when those variables have not been assigned values (which are technically unset)."?

Answer (score 1):

This was accepted as being related to

> the bash 4.4 relase, Entry "f. The `-p' option to declare and similar
>   builtins will display attributes for named variables even when those
>   variables have not been assigned values (which are technically
>   unset)."